# wifi wont stay connected very slow at times

Tags: wireless, broadcom

my wifi wont stay connected, sometimes it disconnects. other times it says its still connected but i cant load any pages etc.
is there any way to fix this?
i just installed ubuntu 14 latest.

output of

> sudo lshw -class network
>
> *-network
>          description: Wireless interface
>          product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
>          vendor: Broadcom Corporation
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
>          logical name: wlan1
>          version: 01
>          serial: you dont need this
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>          configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.1.220 latency=0
>   multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
>          resources: irq:18 memory:b2500000-b2507fff

output of

> lspci
>
> 08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
>   (rev 01)